# Unable to change the font size of MDTextField relative to fit in the screen on_focus

Tags: python, dynamic, kivy, kivymd, textinput

I'm having issue with the MDTextField hint_text font size.
By default when I click inside the MDTextField the hint text gets smaller but I want it to get smaller as per the screen relatively so that irrespective of the length it will get adjusted as per the screen properly.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDRelativeLayout:
    size: dp(200), dp(50)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size      
    
    MDTextField:
        id: fname
        hint_text: 'Enter your fav Book Name'
        multiline: False
        mode: "rectangle"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "y":0.25}
        size_hint: 0.7, 0.6    
'''

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def set_hint_text_font_size(self):
        fname = self.root.ids.fname
        fname.set_hint_text_font_size("20sp") 

TestApp().run()
```

I'm adding images to elaborate my doubt better.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I want that when we deal with the situation as visible in image 2 the font size(of "Enter your fav Book Name") gets auto updated and gets smaller.